# How to close a modal box without the "x"?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to build a modal box in HTML / Javascript and I've found this sample (rif. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp), that's quite good for me ...

I've modified it in this way ....

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 70%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I'd like to avoid the "x" that remain in the modal box (I know .. in this way I can't close le modal box but this is only a sample, in my original code I'll close the modal box in another way .... now I want only avoid to show the "x" inside the box ... ).

I know that I cloud use JQuery but at the moment I'd like don't use it and using simply HTML / Javascript

Suggestions / examples?

Comment: Remove <span class="close">&times;</span>?

Answer (score 1):

Click outside the `modal-content` to close the modal.
Also removed the `x`

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 70%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
 if (target.getAttribute('id') === 'myModal') {
     modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Run code snippet" doesnt work for you?
Could you be a bit specific exactly what it is that doesnt work?

Comment: Seems like I didnt pass the event object to the event callback (for some reason it worked when I tried it). Sorry for beeing a bit fast.
Feel free to remove the srcElement check.

Answer (score 1):

This is my example, hope help you.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
#modal-content {

    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:15%; /* 15% left | 70% center | 15% right*/
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 70%;
    display: none;
    z-index:1 ; /* Sit on top */
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

</div>

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div id="modal-content">
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>



<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var modalContent = document.getElementById('modal-content');



// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalContent.style.display = "block";
}

    var x = document.getElementById("myModal");
        x.onclick = function () {
          modal.style.display = "none";
          modalContent.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```